# modify empty characters in a character array

Tags: java, string

I'm attempting to take in a string from the console of a certain length and set the empty characters in the string to an asterisk.

```
System.out.println("Enter a string of digits.");

        someString = input.next();

        if(someString.matches("\\d{0,9}")) {

            charArr = someString.toCharArray();

            for ( char digit: charArr) {
                if(!Character.isDefined(charArr[digit])){
                    charArr[digit] = '*';
                }
            }

            System.out.printf("Your string is: %s%n", new String(charArr));
```

This code is throwing an array index out of bounds exception and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you could do it in one line with:

```
newString  = someString.replaceAll("\\s", "*");
```

"\s" is the regex pattern for a whitespace character.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, but I found a different solution. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

`for ( char digit: charArr)` will iterate over each character from `charArr`.
Thus, `digit` contains a character value from `charArr`.

When you access the element from `charArr` by writing `charArr[digit]`, you are converting `digit` from datatype `char` to `int` value.

For example, you have `charArr = new char[]{'a','b','c'}`.
`charArr['a']` is equivalent to `charArr[97]` but `charArr` has size of length 3 only.

Thus, `charArr` cannot access the element outsize of its size and throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

---

Solution: loop through the array index wise rather than element wise.

```
for(int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++) {
   // access using charArr[i] instead of charArr[digit]
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop statement:

```
for (char digit: charArr) {
```

iterates the *values* in the array.  The values have type `char` and can be anything from 0 to 65535.  However, this statement

```
    if (!Character.isDefined(charArr[digit])) {
```

uses `digit` as an *index* for the array.  For that to "work" (i.e. not throw an exception), the value needs to be in the range `0` to `charArr.length - 1`.  Clearly, for the input string you are using, some of those values are not acceptable as indexes (e.g. `value >= charArr.length`) and an exception ensues.

But you don't want to fix that by testing `value` is in the range required. The values of `value` are not (from a semantic perspective) array indexes anyway.  (If you use them as if they are indexes, you will end up missing some positions in the array.)

If you want to index the values in the array, do this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++) {
```

and then use `i` as the index.

---

Even when you have fixed that, there is still a problem with your code ... for some usecases.

If your input is encoded using UTF-8 (for example) it could include Unicode codepoints (characters) that are greater than 65535, and are encoded in the Java string as two consective `char` values.  (A so-called *surrogate pair*.)  If your string contains surrogate pairs, then `isDefined(char)` is not a valid test.  Instead you should be using `isDefined(int)` and (more importantly) iterating the Unicode codepoints in the string, not the `char` values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing your `for` blocks. In your example, you're going over every character in your `someString.toCharArray()` so you can't do `!Character.isDefined(charArr[digit])` because digit is a char, not an int. You can't take the index of an array with a char.

If you're checking purely if a character is a space, you can simply do one of the following:

1. `if (digit != ' ')`
2. `if (!Character.isWhiteSpace(digit)`
3. `if (Character.isDigit(digit))`